# Why find the Hamming Distance in Dynamical Networks?

Tags: graph

In dynamical networks, one may calculate the Hamming distance to compare the similarity between two graphs, can anyone explain how?

Assuming that the Hamming distance of two graphs have equal edge density, what is the difference between Hamming distance and expected Hamming distance between two independent Erdos-Renyi random graphs? How does the later arise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hamming distance measures the minimum number of substitutions required to change (transform) one mathematical 'object' (i.e. strings or binary) into another.

So in network theory it can be defined as a the number of different connections between two networks (it can be formulated also for not equally-sized networks and for weighted or directed graphs). In a simple case in which you have two Erdos-Renyi networks (the adjacency matrix has 1 if the node pair is connected and 0 if not) the distance is mathematically defined as follows:

[image]

The values that are subtracted are the two adjacency matrix. If you take two Erdos-Renyi networks with wiring probability of 0.5 and compute the hamming distance between them you should get a value around 0.5. I generated different Erdos-Renyi graph and their Hamming distances produced a Gaussian curve around 0.5 (as we can expect; see below).
[image]

If it is needed I can give you the code I used.